# Take groceries in checked luggage

Tags: schengen, customs-and-immigration, airports, food-and-drink

Can I take rice, dal, dried fish and spices from bangalore to paris in hold- in luggage on al international flight ?

Comment: As Willeke says in her answer, what matters is whether you are allowed to import plant and seafoods. As a rule of thumb products of non-EU origin are restricted or prohibited, as explained here (info is for the UK but the rules are likely to apply equally across the EU) https://www.gov.uk/bringing-food-animals-plants-into-uk/plants

Comment: You also have to declare the food to customs on arrival. If you don't declare the food and get caught with it you could receive very large fines, even if the food is allowed into the country.

Comment: Maybe leave the fish behind. The other stuff might be fine.

Answer (score 10):

It is the departure airport which decide whether you can bring items with you on the plane, but I have never heard of any that does not allow dried food.

So you can bring them in your luggage, the question will be whether you can take them into France, as some items may not be allowed in.
Your question is not detailed enough to answer that.

It is rather likely you can even take the items in your carry-on, all dried foods would fit the rules. It does not matter where you carry the items, as you will get your luggage before going through customs where you need to declare your food items.

It is not really needed to bring groceries, as you can easily buy most in France, although you might get different versions of the foods.

Comment: that being said, you can't get anything even vaguely approaching the quality of those four items, in paris, as in the subcontinent

Comment: That is nonsense. You may not get the variation, what is available is good quality. Just have to look for the right shops, supermarkets may have some but shops specialized in Indian food will have all and at high quality.

Comment: that's not been my experience, but anyway, it's an incidental issue

Answer (score 2):

Animal products are allowed only in small quantities, see https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/carry/meat-dairy-animal/index_en.htm:

> If you are arriving in the EU, [...] you may not bring with you any
>   meat or dairy products without official veterinary documentation. You
>   are, however, allowed to bring in powdered infant milk, baby food and
>   foods required for medical reasons - subject to some restrictions. You
>   are also allowed to bring in limited quantities - for personal
>   consumption - of other animal products including fish products, snails
>   and honey.

See https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/HTML/?uri=CELEX:02009R0206-20130701&from=EN for details.

Comment: Vegetables for food are often also allowed but check per group, as it is not always true.